# how to clean the cart when leaving the woocommerce website

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using this code to clean the cart:

```
/ * empty cart if user come to homepage * /
add_action ('init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url');
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url () {
global $ woocommerce;

if ($ _SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'] === '/') {
    $ woocommerce-> cart-> empty_cart ();
 }
}
```

It cleans when I access the main page, I would like it to clean every time the client closes my site.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you **do not want to clean the cart** when the user leaves. If anything, you want to keep the contents of the cart for when they come back, thus optimizing for selling.

The contents of the cart is most probably linked to the session ID, so it will eventually be lost anyway when the user's session expires.

---

If you want to do it after all, here is a **possible solution:**
In order to detect "leaving" of a website, some client-side code is needed; you cannot achieve this solely with server-side code.

Namely, you will want to use JavaScript and hook into the [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event)* event and then send an asynchronous request to the server using the [Beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API), which can then execute the cleanup. You need to use the beacon API, because:

> Unlike requests made using XMLHttpRequest or the Fetch API, the browser guarantees to initiate beacon requests before the page is unloaded and to run them to completion.

* Please note that the `unload` event is not fully reliable. See [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event) for more details.